# Big InnoDB tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

There are 10 InnoDB partitioned tables. MySQL is configured with option innodb-file-per-table=1 (innodb-file per table/partition - for some reasons). Tables size is abount 40GB each. They contains statictics data.

During normal operation, the system can handle the load. The accumulated data is processed every N minutes. However, if for some reason, there was no treatment for more than 30 minutes (eg, maintenance of the system - it is rare, but once a year is necessary to make changes), begin to lock timeout.

I will not tell you how to come to such an architecture, but it is the best solution - way was long.
Еach time, making changes requires more and more time. Today, for example, a simple ALTER TABLE took 2:45 hours. This is unacceptable.

So, as I said, processing the accumulated data requires a lot of resources and SELECT statements are beginning to return lock timeout errors. Of course, the tables in the query are not involved, and the work goes to the results of queries to them. Total size of these 10 tables is about 400GB, and a few dozen small tables, the total size of which is comparable to (and maybe not yet) to the size of an big table. Problems with small tables there.

My question is: how can I solve the problem with a lock timeout error? A server is not bad - 8 core xeon, 64 RAM. And this is only the database server. Of course, the entire system is not located on the same machine. 
There is an only reason why I get this errors: on data transfrom process from big tables to small.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Percona toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) might alleviate some of your issues with altering a table

Comment: Percona server is installed. Will this Percona toolkit safer then the native MySQL? And how much this toolkit is faster? I can't loose any data. Restoring from backup can take more then 24 hours. _Percona Toolkit is mature, proven in the real world, and well tested, but all database tools can pose a risk to the system and the database server._

Comment: Percona toolkit's `pt-online-schema-change` is safe, speaking from experience. Natively, MySQL's ALTER TABLE may create a copy of your table with changes requested by ALTER TABLE. Writes, and reads, may be locked out at different stages of its operations. `pt-online-schema-change` does similar work but reduces locking. Always test on a non-production database.

Comment: Thanks. I'll thought about it. But now, I need to do something on production db.

Comment: I'll second the vote for pt-osc.  It makes `ALTERs` essentially non-invasive.

Comment: What is the problem?  Is an `ALTER` causing timeouts in other queries?  If so, let's see the `ALTER`, together with the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be a work-around.

Comment: Understood. But the main question is how to to `INSERT` without blocking for `SELECT`. `INSERT DELAYED` will help, but it can work only for `ISAM`, `MyISAM` - not for `InnoDB`.